# React onClick add an X to the cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on **Tic Tac Toe** in React (without JSX) and I get to the point where I need to learn how to use **onClick** such that when a cell is clicked an 'X' will appear in the cell.

After researching, I haven't quite been able to figure it out yet due to all of the syntactical differences in React out there.

How can I update my code so that an X will appear in a clicked cell?

```js
const e = React.createElement;

function cell(props) {
  return e('div', { className: "cell", 
                   id: props.number, 
                   // onClick: someFunctionThatWillAddX
                  }, 
           // props.cellValue
          )
}

let cells = [];
for(i=1; i<= 9; i++){
  cells.push(e(cell, { number: i, cellValue: i}, ))
}

const grid = e('div', { className: 'grid'}, cells);

const container = e('div', { className: 'container'}, grid);

ReactDOM.render(container, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.container {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.cell {
   /* center the cell content */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: what in your code is keep tracking of the state?

Comment: I don't understand how to use state yet. Open to suggestions.

Comment: so learn. state is the answer to your question https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Yes, state and onclick somehow. But I can't find any example of how, which is why I am turning to SO.

Comment: are you not reading the official documentation??

Comment: The official documentation seems to only show examples with JSX.BTW: I already read this page: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html but it doesn't show how to use onclick.

Comment: there's nothing magic about `onClick`. step 1) get the click to work: `{ onClick: () => { console.log('hello world') } }` step 2) setState instead of console log `{ onClick: () => { this.setState({ clicked: true }) } }`

Comment: I think you have all the information in this stackoverflow question that you need. look at Ben's answer and just swap the jsx for createElement and you're done

Comment: In the midst of reading his solution, he deleted it!

Comment: Okay, this worked: `onClick: () => { console.log('hello world') }'

Comment: So I take it I need a function called setState and a prop called clicked.

Comment: created and answer. listerally can't be more thorough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I say that you need `state`, what I really mean is that you're describing "states". There's a state where cells are empty and state where cells contain the text `X`.

In React, the idea is that `render` should be called everytime some state changes. This either means that you keep track of your own state and call `ReactDOM.render` again yourself OR you use React's internal state management and React will call `ReactDOM.render` on your behalf.

To say the latter strategy is more popular is a huge understatement (hehe, pun not intended) so lets just look at that.

step 1)

create a stateful component:

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { clicked: false } // set initial state
  }
  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      'div', 
      { 
        className: "cell", 
        // on click calls setState and flips the `clicked` state
        onClick: () => this.setState({ 
          clicked: !this.state.clicked
        })
      },
      // set the children value based on the current state
      this.state.clicked ? 'X' : '' 
    )
  }
}
```

step 2) render that thing exactly the same when you did `cell` above, but it's called `Cell` now (capitalized) You're done!

`this.setState` is a special function that gets added to your class component via the extention `React.Component` (`class Foo extends React.Component`) and whenever state changes React will take care of updating the view for you.

Hope that helps

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the detailed explanation and solution.

Comment: Strange thing about this. This works perfectly in Chrome, but in Firefox, when the X appears it is always selected. I have to click outside of the grid in order to deselect the X.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try. Replace your 'someFunctionThatWillAddX' with the following:

```js
onClick: function(e) {
  e.target.innerHTML = "X";
}
```

Comment: This is not appropriate for a React application

Comment: I don't see you providing any solutions. This is a simple answer to someone who clearly isn't very familiar with react. Also assuming they're building for a web app.

Comment: Your answer will break on re-renders though. React is keeping track of the virtual DOM in memory. If you change the actual DOM it will get out of sync with virtual DOM. Simplicity is fine as long as it actually works